# Create unique objects in array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, unique-index

My problem is that i want to create an array of objects in which i want uniqueness of object based on two values of object.
Something like creating a key based on two values of object and see if it is unique than push the object in array else don't do anything.

Code is here

```
// Schema
let schema = new Schema({

// accessing info of article
    info: [{
        // don't need to generate separate id
        _id: false,

        impression: {
            type: Boolean,
            validate: {
                validator: validator.isBoolean
            }
        },

        // article accessed by IP
        IP: {
            type: String,
            default: 'NULL'
        },

        // time of accessing article
        time: {
            type: Date,
            default: new Date()
        }
    }]
});
```

here i want to check if **pair of IP and impression** exists then don't do anything else push it in the info array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Must this couple of value be unique in document array ,or in entire collection?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of push into array, use $addToSet. However, you will encounter the same problem because of the time. If you can manage to put that time somewhere else in the schema, you can use addToSet as it only pushes unique elements to the array.

```
const newInfo = {
    impression:{validate: true},
    IP:{"192.168.1.1"}
}

schema.update(
    ...
    {$addToSet: newInfo}
);
```

You may have already solved the problem. Please don't leave the questions unattended after you have found the solution.